# Yii framework 1 how to show nice framework errors again?

Tags: php, yii

I remember that yii used to show nice errors with an awesome stacktrace. How do I get a helpful error again?
Now I get rather unhelpful framework errors (as xdebug does well for php errors) like this:

> Error 404
>
> The system is unable to find the requested action "symbols".

No line number, no trace.

error.php:

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */
/* @var $error array */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name . ' - Error';
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Error',
);
?>

<h2>Error <?php echo $code; ?></h2>

<div class="error">
<?php echo CHtml::encode($message); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

be sure in you `app\index.php` you have a proper YII_DEBUG  configuration

```
// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3); // development configuration 
//defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',0); // production configuration
```

Comment: Yes this is present in `index.php`

Comment: The errors message  with the trace of all the level of code is enabled by defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);..  but seems to remener that the error message for http is not managed by this error showing system ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using default `Yii` `main.php` file then all the logs go to your `protected/runtime/application.log file`. It will include standard Yii logs as well as you own `Yii::log()` calls too.

To see error in Yii you have two change in two places 
1st in index.php

```
// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true); // you can also set trace levels
```

second in `config/main.php`

```
'preload'=>array('log')
```